# Seeking UK School performance data

Tags: geospatial, uk, education

I am looking for UK school performance data.

I don't know what format that comes from, but I want to compare results achieved by pupils, for instance average number and grade of O and A levels per pupil, preferably over at least 5 years.

It would be a bonus if I could chose the subjects, and lean heavily towards STEM, but that's not "must have", just nice to have.

Apparently, house prices in the UK are ridiculously expensive, and a friend in the UK wants me to correlate house prices to education, so that they can find a good school and a relatively affordable house nearby.

I imagine that I will post a second question asking for UK house price data, but the potential problem is that I need them to have the same geolocation data. It is not of much use if one dataset is at town/city level while the other is at post code level. Unless, of course, they can be easily converted, so, any dataset that helps towards that end would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

School performance data is collected by the Department for Education (DfE) and can be accessed via the gov.uk web site - https://www.gov.uk/school-performance-tables

The types of data available (for 2018-19 anyway) are:

- School information

#### Performance

- Final key stage 2
- Final key stage 4
- Provisional key stage 4
- Key stage 4 qualification and subject data
- Final 16 to 18 study
- 16 to 18 value added - qualification type data
- 16 to 18 qualification and subject data
- 16 to 18 value added - subject data
- Apprenticeships data
- 16 to 18 Maths and science A levels

#### Pupil destinations

- Revised key stage 4 pupil destinations
- Revised 16 to 18 student destinations
- Revised 16 to 18 progression to higher education or training
- Provisional key stage 4 pupil destinations

#### Absence and pupil population

- Pupil absence
- Census (detail about pupil types)

#### Workforce and finance

- Workforce
- Spend per pupil
- Spend per pupil (grouped data)
- Spend per pupil (full dataset)

#### Multi-academy trust data

- Key stage 2
- Key stage 4
- 16 to 18 study

It looks like it comes as Excel files (even if you select CSV in the download) and you have to do your own joining from the school information table to the actual performance data. The geography of the school can probably be inferred from it's post code but I don't know if that works for say multi-site academy chains.

Comment: Great answer, thanks (+1). "The geography of the school can probably be inferred from it's post code but I don't know if that works for say multi-site academy chains" - then I shall ignore those, because I imagine that I can probably get house prices per post code (a new question, if it has not already been asked). Convert post codes to lat/long, then find what is "near"

Comment: Worth checking how many schools share a postcode as a first check.

Comment: If I understand UK postcodes, that is extremely unlikely, possibly impossible. They tend to cover 20 houses or so, with most streets having multiple postcodes.. I suppose that there ***might*** be an edge case, with two adjacent  schools. I will add some checks somehow to my code. Thanks for raising the possibility (+1)

Comment: My concern was with an academy "chain" where several schools share an administrative centre (and postcode) which doesn't match their actual location.

Comment: I see. I was not aware of this. Well, caveat emptor". If i ever develop this software, I would expect my friend to perform due diligence before laying out large sums of money and risking his children's education. Fortunately, I know that he will do so. But, do you have any suggestions as to how my software could flag this situation? Thanks (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Someone has already done some of the hard work for you.

[MyEd is a small business](https://myed.com/about-myed) that combines open data about educational performance, environmental data and some user generated data to provide students and parents impartial information about schools and colleges.

You can search their website for schools by postcode - you'll have to do your own research into house prices. Good luck :)

https://myed.com/